# Is there a way to create the logic for Quote "CREATE PDF" button?

Tags: approval-process, quote

Can we put the logic for the CREATE PDF button wherein this button should only be available when opportunity.status=Approved?
​
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In quote, there is a standard pdf button, its can't replace by a custom pdf button. But the workaround for your case would be to create record types and page layouts. Yo can create two record types for the Quote, one with the button and one without.  Once the Opp status is approved, it will change to the second record type by a workflow rule, where there is the button